# Can I trigger google analytics events for a user from different environments?

Tags: google-analytics

We are trying to have a full view of user journeys through the web application we are developing. In the middle of the journey, there's no problem because it's more or less a traditional web application, but the beginnings and the end are not usual.

The journey begins with us sending email to the customers (don't worry, it's not spam). Is it possible to send events to Google Analytics about email being sent? I can include the `UserID` in those events. If I then implement user id in my web application, would I be able to correlate emails send to website visits?

At the other end of the journey, the conversions don't happen by the user that's being coverted but by a manager manually marking the user as converted in a sort-of admin-side to the web application. Can I then again inject the event that the user was converted with the appropriate `UserID`? Will Google Analytics then be able to map the whole journey? Do I need anything else?

The goal is for those events to end up mapped in the charts that look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do what you're asking in a CRM.

That said, I think what you CAN do is use campaign tracking and track the links in the email sent to the users. This way you'd know if they've acted on the emails or not.

Then you'd be able to track them on your site when they interact with the email. If there are CTAs on your site for the users to contact a manager to be converted, then you can track those as events, then set up goals around these events to see conversions.

Comment: I'm aware of sending extra parameters on URLs in emails. I'm not sure why I'd need a CRM on top of the web application I'm developing. I don't want the CTA to be marked as a conversion but the action by the manager to mark the user as converted.

Comment: Because the functionality you're describing is one of a CRM. If you're really adamant of doing it all in GA, you can look into Google Measurement Protocol, which is what's behind GA: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/ I didn't want to recommend it because Google captures a bunch of data related to each hit and sending hits from your server would throw off other measurements if you were ever to look them.

Comment: We are trying to do analytics over a multi-tenant white-label product. Our customers use a CRM to keep track of their consumers. I don't see how a CRM would help us get analytics on how the users are behaving globally, at least no CRM that I ever used. Which one did you have in mind? You are correct that sending events to Google throws off the stats as it considers that a visitor is coming from the server where the events are triggered.

Comment: If that's the case then you should adjust your application to send the information to your customer's CRM instead of GA, when the user arrives at your website, track them using their user id and your customers would need to merge their CRM data with GA data to do client level analysis.

Comment: We want to see this information ourselves, not show it our customers. What CRM were you thinking of that could show this kind of information: https://www.techwyse.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/User-Flow-City.png

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186313/can-i-trigger-google-analytics-events-for-a-user-from-different-environments